# htaccess how to get rid of optional last directory listing seperator?

Tags: .htaccess

I am using .htaccess to rewrite my urls, for example

```
RewriteRule ^jobs/([^/]+)$ jobs.php?job_id=$1  [QSA,L]
```

this works fine for

```
http://www.xxx.com/jobs/980
```

but this fails

```
http://www.xxx.com/jobs/980/
```

is there a way to write this in one line without having redo the same pattern line with backslash again...?

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this:

```
RewriteRule ^jobs/(.*)/?$ jobs.php?job_id=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^jobs/([^/]+)/?$ jobs.php?job_id=$1  [QSA,L]
```